# How to configure shrewsoft vpn in windows with multilevel certificates

Tags: windows-7, vpn, certificate, shrew

I have a linux box already connected with racoon to the same VPN using the same certificates no problem.

From windows, it says "unable to verify remote peer certificate" and I believe it is because I have the server certs concatenated in the .pem file, root and intermediate.

Now, for some reason shrewvpn seems not to recognise the second cert in the file and fails with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the  solution:
There is a folder `C:\\Program Files\ShrewSoft\VPN Client\certificates` where you can drop any secondary certificate you might need and the client will read from there.